# How to change loss / metrics to mean_absolute_percentage_error (MAPE)?

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

I'm learning Keras in R and would like to build and optimize a NN model with minimum `Mean_absolute_percentage_error` (MAPE).

I've found this example on the official documentation [page](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/tutorial_basic_regression.html) but it reports `Mean_absolute_error`
How may I adapt that code to optimize MAPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this can be solved by checking the official documentation of keras. The [metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/) function is what you were looking for.  In keras the performance of a model is judged by the metrics function.

The [documentation](https://keras.io/metrics/) of metrics states:

> "A metric function is similar to a loss function, except that the
>   results from evaluating a metric are not used when training the model.
>   You may use any of the loss functions as a metric function."

If you want to optimize the model with the mean_absolute_percentage_error, you should look for the loss function and not for the metrics. But it is actually the same to change it. Since you asked your question regarding to the `mean_absolute_error`, i assume you want to change the metrics.

So in the example you easily can change the metrics parameter with any [loss](https://keras.io/losses/#mean_absolute_error) function. Of course also the mean_absolute_percentage_error.

```
build_model <- function() {

  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu",
                input_shape = dim(train_data)[2]) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1)

  model %>% compile(
    loss = "mse",
    optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
    metrics = list("mean_absolute_percentage_error")
  )

  model
}

model <- build_model()
model %>% summary()
```

Just do the same in the plots.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot(history, metrics = "mean_absolute_percentage_error", smooth = FALSE) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5)) #you should change lims accordingly
```

If you want to change the loss function use this in your model build.

```
loss = "mean_absolute_percentage_error",
```

Edit: I accidentally used the python documentation in this answer, since the r [documentation](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/metric_binary_accuracy.html) uses another syntax. But it does not a make a difference here, since we just use the loss function name. You can also use it like this: `metrics = metric_mean_absolute_percentage_error`. The python documentation is sometimes more detailed in the explanations what the functions do.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I'd need to change also the loss="mse" to become loss = "mean_absolute_percentage_error"?

Comment: @nba2020 when you want the model to train on the result of mean_absolute_percentage_error, yes.

Comment: do you maybe know @mischva11 what is the scale of mean_absolute_percentage_error that is being outputted after fitting the model? I had to adjust the ylim = c(0, 100) to have something visible in the plot. Does it mean that MAPE value of 30 stands for 30%?